# How can I group intra-day time periods into groups of 15 minutes in SAS more efficiently?

Tags: sas

I am trying to divide the trading hours of 9:30 am - 4:00 pm into 15 minute intervals. I want to do an analysis for each 15 minute interval separately. How can I simplify the below code as opposed to repeating that if statement for 26 intraday 15 minute intervals?

I need to have a variable named interval as below because then I can choose to run my analysis only on certain intervals such as "if interval<3".

Thanks.

```
int=(minute+(hour-9)*60)-29;
if int<16 then interval=1;
if int=>16 and int< 31 then interval=2;
if int=>31 and int< 46 then interval=3;
if int=>46 and int< 61 then interval=4;
```

Comment: Modulus `int` by 15 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interval=ceil(((minute+(hour-9)*60)-30)/15);

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Is it possible to differentiate between different intervals with an addition to this code? For example interval=1 would be the first 15 minutes of the day, interval=2 would be the second 15 minutes of the day etc. Thanks.

Comment: Well, this is exactly what this statement does: assigns interval=1 to the first 15 minutes of the day, interval=2 to the second etc. Or is it not what you meant?

Answer (score 2):

A more SASsy way is to use [INTCK](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1md4mx2crzfaqn14va8kt7qvfhr.htm).

```
*Create test dataset;
data have;
format trade_time TIME9.;
do trade_time = '09:00:00't to '16:00:00't by 480;
  output;
end;
run;

data want;
set have;
interval = intck('MINUTE15','09:00:00't,trade_time)+1;
run;
```

This is a bit simpler math-wise and more flexible in that it can easily calculate any kind of interval.

`intck` takes three arguments in its simplest form: the kind of interval, the starting time, and the ending time, and tells you how many times you crossed an interval boundary to get to that ending time from the starting time.  The kind of interval is a combination of the kind of time unit ('MINUTE','MONTH','HOUR', whatnot) and a pair of numbers separated by a decimal if required; left hand is the number of the interval, right hand is the shift (so if you want to start your 15 minute interval at the 5 minute mark, it would be `MINUTE15.5`).

Comment: Thanks so much for this.I need to have a variable named interval as below because then I can choose to run my analysis only on certain intervals such as "if interval<3".

Comment: I also converted my time stamp into a variable called int. For example int=1 equals the first minute of the trading day. Can I use intck with that variable as opposed to the time format you suggest?Thanks.